# State Machines and Android. Is there a way to only show the methods that are available at a certain State?

Tags: android, button, methods, state

Greetings good people of Stack Overflow.

I am in need of the help of anyone who knows a bit about State Machines and/or Android Development.

So, I've pretty much got the whole design of my app's card game down, I've solved it with a State Machine Design Pattern, I have a CardGame class which in itself manages the different states that the GameState Class can go through and the transitions between them.

Now, my problem is that I do not know how to merge this Design Pattern into my Android App. The main issue is that I can't figure out how to only show a certain Player the actions he can carry out at the certain State the game is at. For example, once the game has just begun, the first Player should only be able to choose 3 of the 15 actions (methods) that the CardGame class allows.

If it where a simple command driven program, once a player would choose an action that he could not execute at a certain time, the program itself would simple printout a "You cannot carry out this action right now, choose another one." or something of that sort, but being it an Android App that manages Buttons and their OnClickListeners, I certainly have not found it to be very easy. I would be grateful if anyone could orient me as to what a viable solution would be, if there is, of course, a way to solve this inconvenient.

**Is there a way to manage what Buttons should be printed according to the availability of a certain State's methods? Can one use some sort of flag to notify what the unavailable methods are in any way?**

Thanks in advance, Agustin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a set to store currently valid actions, and update the set (and redraw buttons) when relevant state is changed.